# Get all values from drop down except selected one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have drop down menu with some random values. When I select the value onchange event triggers and I want to add new drop down under it, but the new one should have all values except selected one in first drop down.
Now when I change value of second one, I need third one that has only non selected values from previous two drop downs. 
What is the easiest way to do this in javaScript?

What I have for now is mechanism for adding new dropdowns, but for now I am filling it with some dummy data.
I need to implement function which I can call instead of dateGenerate()

I have to solve this without using jQuery :(

This is HTML:

```
Test:<br>
<select id="ddlTest" onchange="addNewTestDrop('newTest');">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Raven">Raven</option>
  <option value="PPA">PPA</option>
  <option value="PPA+">PPA+</option>
  <option value="Basic Knowledge">Basic Knowledge</option>
  <option value="PCT">PCT</option>
</select>
<div id="newTest">
</div>
```

And this is javaScript I have:

```
    function dateGenerate() {
      var date = new Date(), dateArray = new Array(), i;
      curYear = date.getFullYear();
        for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            dateArray[i] = curYear+i;
        }
        return dateArray;
    }

    function addNewTestDrop(divname) {
        var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
        var html = '<select>', dates = dateGenerate(), i;
        for(i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            html += "<option value='"+dates[i]+"'>"+dates[i]+"</option>";
        }
        html += '</select>';
        newDiv.innerHTML= html;
        document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all options except the one that has the same value as the select *(as it's selected)*, clone them, and append to the new select

```
document.getElementById('ddlTest').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var newSelect = document.createElement('select');

    var options = [].slice.call(this.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(function(elem) {
        if (this.value !== elem.value) newSelect.appendChild(elem.cloneNode(true))
    }.bind(this));

    document.getElementById('newTest').appendChild(newSelect);
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/j9d52m6y/1/)

Comment: Sorry, my fault I've didn't mention, but I cannot use jQuery... It's forbidden in this case... @adeneo

Comment: @nemo_87 - then why did you tag the question with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this code as you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selectWrapper = $('#select-boxes');
  
  $(document).on('change', '.dynamic-select', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var optionsLength = (element.find('option').length) - 1; // because we have an empty option
   
    if(optionsLength === 1) {
      return true;
    }
    
    var newSelect = $(this).clone();
    newSelect.find("option[value='" + element.val() + "']").remove();
    newSelect.appendTo(selectWrapper)
  });
  
});
```

```css
.dynamic-select{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="select-boxes">
  <select class="dynamic-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Raven">Raven</option>
    <option value="PPA">PPA</option>
    <option value="PPA+">PPA+</option>
    <option value="Basic Knowledge">Basic Knowledge</option>
    <option value="PCT">PCT</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, works great, but I am unable to use jQuery... This is why this is harder for me hehe... Back to basics... :( @Bilal

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript library. I believe you can do it in JavaScript too very easily. Just need to know the correct functions. I'll try to do it in javascript when free. When you posted the question, it was tagged in JQuery and you didn't mentioned this limitation.

Comment: Thank you, that would be great! :) @Bilal